# Problem with Ledger Nano S and Monero GUI: Invalid password

Tags: monero-wallet-gui, ledger

When I am using the Monero GUI with a Ledger Nano S, it asks me to "Export View Key", and no matter which I option choose, the wallet responds with "Couldn't open wallet: Invalid password".

Does anyone know what the issue is?

Comment: What version of the GUI? What firmware version of the Ledger? What operating system?

Comment: o.13.0.4 GUI, 1.5.5 Ledger Nano S, Windows 10

Comment: In case the issue occurs again, I'd recommend to simply recreate the wallet through the guide I linked.

Answer (score 0):

There is a [known problem](https://github.com/LedgerHQ/ledger-app-monero/issues/29) with Ledger v1.5.5.